# LINEと Alexaのアカウントリンクの時に,友だち追加画面を表示したい

Tags: node.js, line

Alexa、LINEログインとMessaging APIを使って、Alexaと連携したLINE botを作成しています。
以下の記事と同様のことをしています。
記事：https://qiita.com/igarashisan_t/items/d1b2e8283a3feddddf46

ですが、アカウントリンク時に友だち追加画面が表示されません。
アカウントリンク すると、LNIEログイン画面から「Alexaアプリのアカウントリンク が終了しました」という表示の画面に遷移してしまいます。

具体的には以下のことを行いました。
・bot_prompt=aggressiveに設定
・LINEログインコンソールから、作成したbotを指定する
・アプリタイプをwebにする

一度bot_promptを設定せずにアカウントリンクしたので、一度アカウントリンクを切断し再びアカウントリンクしたのですが、友だち追加画面が表示されませんでした。

友だち追加画面が表示されない原因のわかる方、ご回答お願いします。

追記

documentにあったのですが、ユーザーセッションが存在し、scopeをprofileにしている場合は同意画面は表示されないようです。
同意画面と友だち追加画面は違うかもしれませんが、同様の現象が起きているのかもしれません。

参考：https://developers.line.biz/ja/docs/line-login/web/integrate-line-login/#making-an-authorization-request

Answer (score 0):

挙動を見る限り、LINEログインに対する認可付与の際にのみ発生するようです。

つまり、既に認可を与えていた場合、一旦その認可を取り消す必要がありそうです。

Android版LINE appの場合、

1. LINE appホーム画面右上の歯車アイコンをタップし設定画面を開く
2. アカウント > 連動アプリ を順に選択する
3. 対象のLINEログインを削除する

ことで認可を取り消せます。

この状態で `bot_prompt=aggressive` なリンクを踏むと該当イベントが発生します。